# Set data in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown in React. The main problem is calling `renderDetails`.
When I call `this.renderDetails(element, i)` in `renderInfo` directly, everything works and `var text=element.Ruletext` will be shown in `resultRule`. But when `renderDetails` is called in `showDiv = (e,element,i) =>{....` function, `var text=element.Ruletext` will not be shown in `resultRule`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            DetailsInfo: {},
            divVisibles: {},
            resultRule: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="moreInfo" onClick={e => this.showDiv(e, item, i)}>
                        <span>show more data</span>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        id="box-info"
                        key={i}
                        className={` ${!this.state.divVisibles[i] ? "unvisible" : "visible"}`}
                    >
                        <div class="table">{this.state.DetailsInfo[i]}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return <div>{renderInfo}</div>;
    }
    DetailsInfo = i => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            divVisibles: { ...prevState.divVisibles, [i]: !prevState.divVisibles[i] }
        }));
    };
    showDiv = (e, element, i) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            DetailsInfo: { ...prevState.DetailsInfo, [i]: this.renderDetails(element, i) },
            divVisibles: { ...prevState.divVisibles, [i]: !prevState.divVisibles[i] }
        }));
    };
    renderDetails(element, i) {
        var indents = [];
        indents.push(
            <div>
                <span>{this.renderRule(element, i)}</span>
                <div key={i} class="resultRule">
                    {this.state.resultRule[i]}
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return indents;
    }

    renderRule(element, i) {
        return (
            <span class="txtRul" onClick={e => this.handelrule(e, element, i)}>
                show rule text
            </span>
        );
    }
    handelrule = (e, element, i) => {
        var text = element.Ruletext;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            resultRule: { ...prevState.resultRule, [i]: text } ///In this part text does not be set in resultRule ////
        }));
    };
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"));
```

Comment: If you could create a working snippet to test, it would be easier to debug and find the problem. Try codesandbox or codepen.

Comment: Also where is `element.Ruletext` defined? The `Ruletext` property does not seem to be defined anywhere, so I'd expect `text = undefined`

Comment: Hi @Keno Clayton. `Ruletext ` is a name of an object in my json file. `text` is going to be dynamic but if I put a static value instead of `text`, it does not be set in `resultRule`. ` resultRule: { ...prevState.resultRule, [i]: 'test'}`

Answer (score 0):

This might be because inside the DetailsInfo the refernce of "this" passed to renderDetails is of DetailsInfo instead of Class this refernce.
Try using this.

```
     showDiv = (e, element, i) => {
         const classRef=this;
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             DetailsInfo: { ...prevState.DetailsInfo, [i]: 
             this.renderDetails(element, i).bind(classRef)
             },
             divVisibles: { ...prevState.divVisibles, [i]: 
             !prevState.divVisibles[i] }
         }));
     };
```

Comment: Hi @ Vinay Goyal.I tried it. There is this error :`_this.renderDetails(...).bind is not a function`

Comment: @bita You'd need to bind it in the constructor actually. `this.renderDetails = this.renderDetails.bind(this);`

Comment: Sorry I just made a mistake here  this.renderDetails(element,i).bind(classRef), instead of above try using: 
this.renderDetails.bind(classRef,element,i)

Comment: Now `renderDetails` is empty.There is no result.

Comment: @bin , I just used your code snipped with providing  data = {Ruletext:'the rule text'}] for initial rendering purpose and then tried to run the code , I am getting {0: "the rule text"} for resultRule

Comment: Sorry @Vinay Goyal .Actually I did not get what you mean.Can you show me in  code?